# Always run unit tests on x64 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

My projects are running on x64 platform. But the default test settings in VS2017 set X86 as a default processor architecture.

It bothers me bigtime that I have to manually change the setting to X64 every time in this window.

---

[image]

---

I've googled this and found a seemingly right way to do. It's about using a `.runsettings` file as explained in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782531.aspx

I've built a settings file and tried to apply it on VS2017 but the IDE forgets the setups after restarted. I ended up selecting the settings file over and over again. What's worse is that it doesn't work either.

I came up the other way around and tried to find something in `xunit` documentation about fixing X64 as a default processor architecture, but found none.

How can I fix the default processor architecture to X64? If there're some command sort of things, I can definitely use that!

Comment: Have you tried setting the test project itself to be x64 instead of AnyCPU?

Comment: Yes I have. Configuring it as such clears this problem away. But I just want to know how to change the default settings permanently.

Comment: Well, that is also permanent :)  You could also leave it as AnyCPU and clear the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox (or set Prefer32Bit to false in the project).

Comment: It depends IMHO. Assume that there's a process that must run on x64 because it uses in-memory features to hold some large amount of data over 4gb, then setting Any CPU and building the app under the setting will be a bit risky, although the setup would be done on x64 machine as long as the operator knows the detail.

Comment: If it /must/ run on x64 (rather than being x64 by default), then setting the project’s target to x64 explicitly is the appropriate way to do that. If ia64 and arm64 are realistic target platforms, anycpu + do-not-prefer-32bit is better. You could do a 64-bit check (IntPtr’s size) and throw if it ends up being run in a 32-bit environment.